# Make 'interact' use IPython console, rather than standard Python one?

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, pdb, ipdb

In pdb/ipdb debugging, the useful `interact` command gives me a fully featured interactive Python console.

However, this appears to always be the "standard" Python console, even if I use `ipdb` to begin with.  Is there a way to configure ipdb such that `interact` will give me the IPython console, rather than the standard Python one?  Interestingly, I *do* get the IPython style prompt, but I don't get to use IPython magic such as `%whos`:

```
In [24]: 1/0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-05c9758a9c21> in <module>()
----> 1 1/0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

In [25]: %debug
> <ipython-input-24-05c9758a9c21>(1)<module>()
----> 1 1/0

ipdb> interact
*interactive*
In : %whos
  File "<console>", line 1
    %whos
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to get `ipdb`s `interact` to give me the fully featured `IPython` console?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: @dimid Only on the first iteration!  See edit.

Comment: What if you exit (control+d) from `ipdb` after `%debug`?

Comment: @dimid Hmm, I tried again and I cannot fully reproduce the problem I noticed yesterday.  Not sure what was going on, but it works now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `.pdbrc`:

```
import IPython 
[..]
# Interactive shell
alias interacti IPython.embed()
```